# Passing arguments to fsolve when solving system of equations

Tags: python

How to pass arguments to fsolve when you solve a systems of equations? Here's example:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def equations(x,y,a,b):
    return(x+y+a+b,x-y-a-b)

x,y = fsolve(equations,[0,0],args=(1,2))
```

I get:

> TypeError: equations() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

How to pass arguments in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this has to do with passing `args` and having multiple inputs that need to be optimized (i.e. `x` and `y`). The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) for `fsolve` suggest making the first parameter a vector. When I tried your example on my machine, I saw a different but similar error:

```
In [3]: from scipy.optimize import fsolve                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [4]: def equations(x, y, a, b): 
   ...:     return (x+y+a+b, x-y-a-b) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [5]: fsolve(equations, [0, 0], args=(1, 2))
```

Led to

> TypeError: equations() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Which supported my initial hypothesis. A modified version of

```
In [6]: def equations2(xy, a, b): 
   ...:     x, y = xy 
   ...:     return (x+y+a+b, x-y-a-b) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [7]: fsolve(equations2, [0, 0], args=(1, 2)) 
Out[7]: array([ 1.05443151e-16, -3.00000000e+00])
```

So the solution boils down to **combine x and y into a tuple vector**.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, passing arguments into a tuple solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, that I personally prefer to using `args` argument in `fsolve`, is to create a *callable*:

```
class Equations:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

    def __call__(self, x):
        return # code
```

A dirtier, but valid, approach is to use a closure:

```
def Equations(a, b):
    def compute(x):
        return # code
    return compute
```

And then, in both cases,

```
solution = fsolve(Equations(1, 2), [0,0])
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html):

> ```
> scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, x0, args=(), fprime=None, ...
> ```
>
> - `func` : `callable f(x, *args)`
>     A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument.

The function's input variables must be combined into a single list / vector / array / tuple:

```
def equations(z,a,b):
    # z[0] = x, z[1] = y
    return(z[0]+z[1]+a+b,z[0]-z[1]-a-b)

x,y = fsolve(equations,[0,0],args=(1,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def equations(x0,a,b):
    x = x0['x']
    y = x0['y']
    return(x+y+a+b,x-y-a-b)

x,y = fsolve(equations,x0={x:0,y:0},args=(1,2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped!

Comment: could you accept my answer if you like it and if it helped? thanks